# Are the apps that I download from the OS X app store sandboxed?

Tags: macos, mac

Are the apps like TextWrangler sandboxed when I download them from the OS X appstore?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Per the [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/mac/#functionality):

```
2.31 Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected
```

As of [June 1, 2012](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167055/sandboxing_deadline_arrives_what_it_means_for_apple_developers_and_you.html), all apps submitted to the Mac App Store are required to have sandboxing implemented.